# Check if set is a subset of list of sets/multiple sets

Tags: python

Let's say I have `s1={'bread'}` and I have a  `l1 = [{'milk', 'yogurt', 'eggs'}, {'bread', 'milk'}]`. Since `'bread'` is in the second set I want it to return `True`. If I put it in a `for-loop`, it will check if `s1` is in the first element, then it will check if `s1` is in the second element. How can I do it like simultaneously? Something like:

```
s1.issubset(l1[0]) or s1.issubset(l1[1]) or .... s1.issubset(l[n])
```

so that the result will be `True`

Comment: What do you mean by "simultaneously" ?

Comment: better use standard `for` loop. Check with all items and use `or` - `True or False`  gives `True`

Comment: I made an edit, so I want to check if `s1` is a subset of l1[0] or if `s2` is a subset l1[1] and so forth and so on until the last element of the list

Comment: `result = False` `for item in l1: result = result or  s1.issubset(item)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly another option is to convert `l1` into one large set. You can do this with `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
s1 = {'bread'}
s2 = {'toast'}
l1 = [{'milk', 'yogurt', 'eggs'}, {'bread', 'milk'}]

print(s1 <= set(chain(*l1)))
print(s2 <= set(chain(*l1)))
```

will print

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
s1 = {'bread'}
l1 = [{'milk', 'yogurt', 'eggs'}, {'bread', 'milk'}]

print(any(s1.issubset(e) for e in l1))
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Comment: Nice! I think this what I was aiming for. So the `any` method allows me to check it for all, in essence?

Comment: Yes @xndr it does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to check every element and use `or`

```
s1 = {'bread'}
l1 = [{'milk', 'yogurt', 'eggs'}, {'bread', 'milk'}]

result = False

for item in l1:
    result = result or s1.issubset(item)

print(result)
```

or you use `if` to check if it is true and exit loop using break

```
s1 = {'bread'}
l1 = [{'milk', 'yogurt', 'eggs'}, {'bread', 'milk'}]

result = False

for item in l1:
    if s1.issubset(item):
        result = True
        break # exit loop because there is no need to check rest items

print(result)
```